# calculate carbon stored within 1 million square km of tropical forest forest

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Area of tropical forest is 22.6 M km squared, total amount of carbon for this area is 547.8. I need to calculate the amount of carbon stored within one million square kilometres.  547.8/22.6= 24.2 GtC/M km squared.  24.2/13=1.86 (3 SF) Is this right or am I completely off? Thank you

Comment: What are these units: M km, GtC/M km, and what is SF? What uis meaning of division by 13?

Comment: units for the area is Million km square, For carbon Gigatonnes of carbon. the total stored should be GtC/M km squared. 3 Sf significant figures. I thought to calculate the total area 22.6, then reach the 1 million square kilometer

Comment: Jade-- still don't get the divide by 13 step. [You don't mention  the units of that 13  you divide by.]

Comment: I got so frustrated to convert the 24.2 GtC/M square km to just the 1 M square km  (calculate the amount of carbon stored within one million square kilometers) that I just confused the whole process. In all honesty, I don't know why I thought 13 would divide the area to 1 M square km

Comment: I think it should just be the 24.2 (3 SF) number. You divided the total carbon by the number of million kilometers squared. That gives the amount of carbon per million square kilometers. No use of the extra division by 13, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Jade-- was this calculation a question in a text that had an answer in the book? If so did they get 24.2?

Comment: no, it has no answer, it an exercise in calculating carbon stored in specific areas